# Daily, Weekly and Monthly report from MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to get Daily, Weekly and Monthly report from a sql-server table.

Table structure as as follow:

```
------------------------------------------
| ItemID      | CommentDate              |
-----------------------------------------
|989898797    | 2019-04-01 02:51:11.153  |
|----------------------------------------|
|989898797    | 2019-04-01 02:51:11.153  |
|----------------------------------------|
|989898797    | 2019-04-03 02:51:11.153  |
|----------------------------------------|
|989898797    | 2019-04-09 02:51:11.153  |
|----------------------------------------|
|989898797    | 2019-04-11 02:51:11.153  |
|----------------------------------------|
```

So far I have tried the following,

```
select (select count(itemid) from ebayfeedback where ((year(commentdate) = year(getdate())) 
and datepart(m,commentdate)=datepart(m,dateadd(month,-1,getdate())))) as lastmonth,

(select count(itemid) from ebayfeedback where (year(commentdate) = year(getdate())) 
and datepart(m,commentdate)=datepart(m,dateadd(month,0,getdate()))) as thismonth,

(select count(itemid) from ebayfeedback where (year(commentdate) = year(getdate())) 
and datepart(wk,commentdate)=datepart(wk,dateadd(week,1,getdate()))) as lastweek,

(select count(itemid) from ebayfeedback where (year(commentdate) = year(getdate())) 
and datepart(wk,commentdate)=datepart(wk,getdate())  group by datepart(wk,commentdate) ) as thisweek,

(select count(itemid) from ebayfeedback where convert(varchar,commentdate,101)= 
convert(varchar,dateadd(day,-1,getdate()),101)) as yesterday,

(select count(itemid) from ebayfeedback where convert(varchar,commentdate,101)= 
convert(varchar,getdate(),101) ) as today

from ebayfeedback
```

The Result I receive result in multiple rows from the above query is like below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| lastmonth   | thismonth | lastweek | thisweek | today |
---------------------------------------------------------
|5            |    5      |    2     |   2      |  1    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|5            |    5      |    2     |   2      |  1    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|5            |    5      |    2     |   2      |  1    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|5            |    5      |    2     |   2      |  1    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|5            |    5      |    2     |   2      |  1    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

I want single row (1 result) for each period only. Please advise me as how to achieve this. Also is there any best approach other than the one I used.

Desired Result should be one row like below.

---

```
| lastmonth   | thismonth | lastweek | thisweek | today |
---------------------------------------------------------
|5            |    5      |    2     |   2      |  1    |
|-------------------------------------------------------|
```

Note: The data I given in the as example in above both tables not the actual I have.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using conditional aggregation query to create a report based on it.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save is this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ItemID int,
    CommentDate datetime
);

INSERT INTO @T (ItemId, CommentDate) VALUES
(989898797, '2019-04-01T02:51:11.153'),
(989898797, '2019-04-01T02:51:11.153'),
(989898797, '2019-04-03T02:51:11.153'),
(989898797, '2019-04-09T02:51:11.153'),
(989898797, '2019-04-11T02:51:11.153');
```

Declaring local variable to make the query more readable and to prevent some code repetitions:

```
DECLARE @Today date = GETDATE(), -- today's date
        @ThisWeek date = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()), -- first date of the week
        @ThisMonth date = DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()); -- first date of the month
DECLARE @LastMonth date = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @ThisMonth), -- first date of last month
        @LastWeek date = DATEADD(WEEK, -1, @ThisWeek) -- first date of last week
```

The query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN CommentDate >= @LastMonth AND CommentDate < @ThisMonth THEN ItemId END) As LastMonth,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CommentDate >= @ThisMonth AND CommentDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @ThisMonth) THEN ItemId END) As thismonth,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CommentDate >= @LastWeek AND CommentDate < @ThisWeek THEN ItemId END) As lastweek,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CommentDate >= @ThisWeek AND CommentDate < DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @ThisWeek) THEN ItemId END) As thisweek,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CommentDate >= @Today AND CommentDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Today) THEN ItemId END) As today
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
LastMonth   thismonth   lastweek    thisweek    today
0           5           2           0           0
```

Comment: Thanks Zohar, but I don't want result like this, rather I want single count for each period like I given an example already.